# What does "In front of a dirty double-mirror they found me" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, translation

In the song `"I"` by `"Kendrick Lamar"`i hear this :

> As I look around me ,
>   So many wanna down me ,
>   But an enemigo never drown me,
>   In front of a dirty double-mirror they found me ,
>   And I love myself

I can not understand what he means by "In front of a dirty double-mirror they found me".

Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is song lyrics of a kind that is made to be rhythmic, with little actual meaning.

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty Do you mean it hasn't a special meaning and just means a normal dirty double-mirror ?

Comment: I don't know what it means. The entire passage is drivel to me.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Kendrick's lyrics seldom lack actual meaning. This is a song from an album with ample [cultural and political](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Pimp_a_Butterfly#Critical_reception) content. The OP's question is entirely valid, and there *is* a good resource for deciphering the meaning.

Comment: @RuslanD Great, then. Good that you could help the OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Genius](https://genius.com/4087421) website is a great resource for understanding rap lyrics. Click on that particular line in the song for the interpretation.

**EDIT**: Reproducing it here in case links change and it's no longer available:

> A double mirror is a **two-way mirror**. Often found in interrogation rooms, these allow the person on the outside to see through without being seen themselves – while those inside see their reflection.
>
> Kendrick refers to his double mirror as dirty, acting as a metaphor reflecting on his past life and his mistakes – he wasn’t clean.
>
> His fans also began to observe Kendrick and his behavior through the mirror, continuing the metaphor speaking of his music. The listeners began to understand his previous life and the suffering he experienced.